# Is a VirtualBox Host-only Adapter safe?

Tags: virtualization

I have a VM in VirtualBox with two network adapters: a Host-only adapter and a NAT adapter; I was wondering if the VM gets compromised, is my Host-only adapter putting my host in danger?

--- reasoning:

- Host-only to putty in
- NAT for internet access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, **yes** this is a safe configuration.

The VirtualBox host only network appears as a network adapter on your host operating system. You should make sure the firewall rules are applied to that network. For example, on Windows you can do this from "Windows firewall with advanced security". The screenshot below shows that VirtualBox Host-Only Network, and confirms that it is firewalled.

There are still some risks. There may be vulnerabilities in VirtualBox that allow a malicious guest to compromise the host. If you have drive or clipboard sharing enabled, then these carry some risk too. But in general this configuration is fine.

[image: Windows firewall config]